# Jobs visible in Scheduled Jobs, but not in Apex Jobs, why not?

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I have the following class:

```
public class AlertsJobBatch implements Schedulable {
    public AlertsJobBatch() {
    }
    public void execute(System.SchedulableContext SC) {
        Alerts.EvaluateAllPeriodicAlertConfigs();
    }
    public static void schedule() {
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  1', '0  1 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  2', '0  7 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  3', '0 13 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  4', '0 19 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  5', '0 25 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  6', '0 31 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  7', '0 37 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  8', '0 43 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check -  9', '0 49 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
        System.schedule('Periodic alerts check - 10', '0 55 6-20 ? * MON-FRI', new AlertsJobBatch());
    }
}
```

When I use AlertsJobBatch.schedule() to schedule this, I can see 10 jobs in Scheduled Jobs. I can see that they execute at the appropriate times (in Scheduled Jobs), and I can see the results in modified objects. But the jobs are not visible in Apex Jobs. Why is that? In Apex Jobs the results of jobs are visible (Completed/Failed), so I would like them to show up there as well.